# Some Wordpress image thumbnails aren't displaying after switch to new URL

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails

I recently switch the base URL of my Wordpress site. My images are all working, but a lot of the thumbnails don't show up in gallery view.

I checked the file paths, and they're correct, but when I enter the url straight into the browser, it goes to the 404 page, and the console is full of 404 errors.

There doesn't seem to be any difference between the images that show and the ones that don't show.

I fixed the permissions and regenerated all thumbnails, but I have the same results.

This is a Wordpress instance running as the blog of a Magento 2 store with the Fishpig integration.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somes times, Wordpress need to be update also in database contents. Can you try tu use a plugin like WP Migrate DB?

Comment: I just updated to 5.5 and it ran some sort of upgrade script on the DB, but I'll try this one too

Comment: that didn't work. there seems to be something obvious that I'm missing here, because some of them ARE showing up, but even when I navigate straight to the URL, I get a 404

Comment: And what about cache?

Comment: There's a directory called cache in wp-content, but all it has is an empty directory called wph

Comment: @maggiathor It's on the same server. I've only changed the docroot of the blog from /wp to something more secure

Answer (score 0):

Servers have different configurations when it comes to characters, symbols and CAPs/wno Caps when it comes to File-Names. You might need to check for that. You might try it out with one file that doesn't show up and rename it to no-caps, no spaces, no special symbols.